# How can I find the path to the latest installed build-tools in the Android SDK?

Tags: android, windows

If for example I want to run `aapt2.exe` and I have the path to the SDK itself. How would I go about running it?

The path to aapt2 could be something like `C:\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aapt2.exe` or `C:\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.1\aapt2.exe` etc.

Is there any tool provided by the SDK that I can run that would give me the latest installed version of the build-tools? A `some-tool.exe build-tools latest` that would return 29.0.1?